# Automatically generate Devise Authenticity Token on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I currently have an app that uses regular Devise authentication for logging in and out, but uses Devise's token_authenticatable module to create a unique token that is used when submitting data to the app from a bookmarklet. Each user gets a unique bookmarklet with their authenticity token baked right into the javascript. However, the way Devise is currently set up, the user has no auth token by default. They have to go to the /edit/users page, press "Generate Token" and then they have one in the db.

I need a way to tell Devise to automatically generate an auth token for each user at sign up.

I'm a newbie, and I'm not sure where to find the Devise controllers to edit this, and even if I could find them, I'm not entirely sure what I would do. Any help is welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the helper `ensure_authentication_token` of `Devise::Models::TokenAuthenticatable`
 module.

So you `User` class might be like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable

  before_save :ensure_authentication_token
end
```

Comment: will this create a visible token column inside the user table?